# IIS Error for custom messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

Please find attached the error I am getting while trying to display a custom error message. My application ASP.Net 4 and uses IIS 7.5. HEre is my code in web.config.

```
</httpErrors>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your this under system.web

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/WebError.aspx"/>
```

And this under system.webServer (one of a few options)

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```

Comment: Now I get Server Error  as 

Server Error in '/' Application.

 Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: Set customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" so you can get more detail. Txs.

Comment: I did it but does not help. All I want to accomplish is redirect the users when unexpected error happens in the application. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this ?.Thx

Comment: Looks like this simple code 
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/WebError.aspx" mode="On">
      <!--<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/Test.html"/>-->
    </customErrors>  
Works when run it in VisualStudio. But If I publish it to IIS 7.5 and test it ..the code does not display the customer error. ANy idea why ?

Comment: Can you reach the page directly after publishing?  http://mypublishedsvr/myapp/ErrorPages/WebError.aspx

Comment: No I cannot get to /ErrorPages/WebError.aspx directly. Also I saved a Test.html in the same path and can access the html path at /Errorpages/Test.html. What could be going wrong ?.